# Can't compare string received through Bluetooth with normal String

Tags: java, android

I have a connection between Arduino and Android phone.

This is the string that I'm receiving: always the string `555`, I know because I tested it:

```
    final String data = new String(encodedBytes, "US-ASCII");
    String toCompare = data;
```

But this will always print `false` :

```
txtArduino.setText(String.valueOf(toCompare.equals("555")));
```

I think that the format is different or something like that, because I know for sure that I'm receiving `555`.

Comment: I suggest printing the numeric values of each character for each string and comparing by hand.

Comment: Ya, I wonder if it's also sending a random null character at the end, or some obscure whitespace character

Comment: I'll try to do a substring now, to get just the first 3 characters

Comment: I tried substring(0,2) but it's still false

Comment: Let's see the bytes.

Comment: I did  for(byte b:encodedBytes){
                                            Log.d(TAG,String.valueOf(b));}   and what is being printed is 53535313 and the textDisplay shows 555

Answer (score 0, accepted):

53 53 53 13 in ASCII is 5 5 5 ␍

`new String` converts that to Unicode/UTF-16, which as a literal in Java would be "555\r" or "555\u000D". So, you should compare to that.

```
final String data = new String(encodedBytes, "US-ASCII");
String toCompare = data;

txtArduino.setText(String.valueOf(toCompare.equals("555\r")));
```

---

Depending on your Bluetooth library, you might have to consider that you are receiving a *stream* of bytes and that each read gives you all available bytes. It would then be up to you to split the stream into messages. This could be the purpose of the ␍.

Comment: How can I split the stream using ␍ ?

Comment: You should first find out what the behavior of your source for encodedBytes is. Does it return the next "line", "message", or just any available bytes, which could be multiple and fractional lines or messages? If so, you'd have to buffer bytes for those that aren't complete. You should as another question about that.

Answer (score 0):

Your input string includes the newline at the end. Trim it.